# Jams Client illegal characters in path

Tags: powershell

I am getting an "`illegal characters in path`" error with the following code. Any thoughts?

```
$source = \\md\drive\MMM\<<DriveEnv>>\AA\Extracts\Active\filename.csv

$newfilename = \\md\drive\MMM\<<DriveEnv>>\AA\Extracts\Active\filename.csv.TEMP

Rename-Item $source -NewName $newfilename
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the illegal characters and use `Replace` to strip them out in PowerShell. Below is an example how to replace `<` and `>` characters with `NULL` values which basically removes those characters.

It also appears that the `<<` and `>>` are not be valid characters for a folder name in a UNC path. So you might replace those with the valid location or give an example to further test what that is actually set to in your example.

```
$source = "\\md\drive\MMM\<<DriveEnv>>\AA\Extracts\Active\filename.csv"

$source = $source.Replace("<","")
$source = $source.Replace(">","")

$newfilename = $source
$newfilename = $newfilename + ".TEMP"

Rename-Item $source -NewName $newfilename
```

Comment: The `<<` and `>>` characters could work if you use the `-literalPath` parameter, which tells Powershell to use the path exactly as it was typed in.

Comment: It looks like @Mindy is trying to access a file from an external source (note the \\ in the front in the path). If that drive uses another filesystem, which supports `<` and `>`. IIRC ext3, at least, supports all bytes except `\0` and `null` in the filename/foldername. That's what I mean :P